# How to start binary file from Systemd service

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd, executable

So, I have start.sh file to start imagecache service. And I have executable binary file "imgproxy" and I need start it and pass to it two parameters like as text file. 
Body of start.sh file:

```
export IMGPROXY_LOCAL_FILESYSTEM_ROOT="/home/filestorage/media"
export IMGPROXY_BIND=":9608"
./home/tools/imgproxy/imgproxy -keypath ./home/tools/imgproxy/key.txt -saltpath 
./home/tools/imgproxy/salt.txt

ExecStartPre=nohup /bin/bash /home/tools/imgproxy/start.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I starts it with command "ExecStartPre" because I have main service and binary file their dependency. I must start this binary file before starting my main service.

So, when I start service appears following error:

```
systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/imagecache.service:11] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: nohup bash /home/tools...ull 2>&1 &
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An absolute path is the full path to a file starting at the root `/`. It looks like you need to supply the absolute path of `nohup` which on a CentOS 7 system is `/usr/bin/nohup`.

---

I really don't know  the tools you are using but if possible I would be tempted to make the target of the `ExecPreStart` its own service and make the main service dependent on it. The docs for [`systemd.service` are well worth a read](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

Comment: I will try your answer @lain!

Comment: You don't need to nohup something you start in a systemd unit. Just call it directly.